# DNS error: http://URL というエラーが出ます

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-spreadsheet

[スクレイピング練習用サイト](https://scraping-for-beginner.herokuapp.com/ranking/)で、スクレイピングの練習をしています。
ライブラリにversion８の「Perser」プロジェクトのIDを入力して、準備を行い

以下のコードを書いて、セルA2にURLをはりつけて、その値を読み込ませてから、画像以外の情報を取得しようとしましたが、

```
Exception: DNS error: http://URL
myFunction  @ スクレピング検証.gs:6
```

こちらのエラーがでて、読み取れませんでした。
セルからURLをスクレイピングすることはそもそもできないのか？
どこか書き方、メソッドの使い方に誤りがあるのか、教えていただけませんか？

```
function Scraping() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheetURL  = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('URL貼り付け'), true);

 const URL =  sheetURL.getRange('A2').getValue.activate;
  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("URL");
  let content = response.getContentText("utf-8");
  var text = Parser.data(content).from('<dd class="is_rank">').to('</span>').iterate();
console.log(text)
}
```

Comment: 既存の回答への追記として、もしも"URL貼り付け"シートの"A2"にURLがあるのであれば、`const URL = sheetURL.getRange('A2').getValue.activate;`は、`undefined`を返し、既存回答を反映させてもエラーが発生してしまうことを心配しました。この場合、`const URL = sheetURL.getRange('A2').getValue();`に修正してみてください。`getValue`は、Class Rangeのメソッドです。[Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

エラーメッセージを見てみましょう。

> `Exception: DNS error: http://URL`

この `URL` という文字列がどこから来たのか考える必要が有ります。

こういう場合は、エラーメッセージに含まれるエラーが出た場所（ファイル名、関数名、何行目か、など）からたどっていくのが方法の一つです。今回は環境が特殊（Apps Script）ということもあり、質問からはエラーの箇所が特定できないので、ざっと見で該当していそうな箇所を指摘します。

```js
let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("URL");
```

ここで文字列の `"URL"` が渡されていますので、これが原因でしょう。おそらく質問者さんは、変数の `URL` を渡そうと意図されたと思います。つまり、クォート（`"` と `"`）で囲まずに、ただ `URL` と書けばよいでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
追記メッセージ含めて、とても分かりやすい回答でした。
おっしゃられた通り修正して、実際にどう動くか検証してみますね

Comment: おっしゃっていた場所、コメント通りの理由で間違っておりました。
スクレイピングそのものはできましたが、想像していたのとは違う情報が取得されていたので、From（）とTo（）に入れるべき情報を自分が間違えているのだと思います。
色々試して、挙動が不明であったりすれば、それは別の質問を立ててみます。

改めて回答いただきありがとうございます。
この質問そのものは回答済みとさせていただきますね。